# Mouseleave delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to delay the zoomed image disappearing by a X seconds so I can fade out the image rather than it simply disappearing.

Can I simply add **.delay(1000)** somewhere to the mouseleave / hide lines of code?

I've tried that but unfortunately doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to wrap a **setTimeout( ... , 1000);** around various parts of the code, but couldn't make that work either.

Any help much appreciated!

Here is the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mr_antlers/nh5jw5tb/2/

This is the original 'EasyZoom' .js code.

```
        /*!
 * @name        EasyZoom
 * @author      Matt Hinchliffe <>
 * @modified    Tuesday, September 6th, 2016
 * @version     2.4.0
 */

! function (a) {
    "use strict";
function b(b, c) {
    this.$target = a(b), this.opts = a.extend({}, i, c, this.$target.data()), void 0 === this.isOpen && this._init()
}
var c, d, e, f, g, h, i = {
    loadingNotice: "Loading image",
    errorNotice: "The image could not be loaded",
    errorDuration: 2500,
    linkAttribute: "href",
    preventClicks: !0,
    beforeShow: a.noop,
    beforeHide: a.noop,
    onShow: a.noop,
    onHide: a.noop,
    onMove: a.noop
};
b.prototype._init = function () {
    this.$link = this.$target.find("a"), this.$image = this.$target.find("img"), this.$flyout = a('<div class="easyzoom-flyout" />'), this.$notice = a('<div class="easyzoom-notice" />'), this.$target.on({
        "mousemove.easyzoom touchmove.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onMove, this),
        "mouseleave.easyzoom touchend.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onLeave, this),
        "mouseenter.easyzoom touchstart.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onEnter, this)
    }), this.opts.preventClicks && this.$target.on("click.easyzoom", function (a) {
        a.preventDefault()
    })
}, b.prototype.show = function (a, b) {
    var g, h, i, j, k = this;
    if (this.opts.beforeShow.call(this) !== !1) {
        if (!this.isReady) return this._loadImage(this.$link.attr(this.opts.linkAttribute), function () {
            (k.isMouseOver || !b) && k.show(a)
        });
        this.$target.append(this.$flyout), g = this.$target.width(), h = this.$target.height(), i = this.$flyout.width(), j = this.$flyout.height(), c = this.$zoom.width() - i, d = this.$zoom.height() - j, 0 > c && (c = 0), 0 > d && (d = 0), e = c / g, f = d / h, this.isOpen = !0, this.opts.onShow.call(this), a && this._move(a)
    }
}, b.prototype._onEnter = function (a) {
    var b = a.originalEvent.touches;
    this.isMouseOver = !0, b && 1 != b.length || (a.preventDefault(), this.show(a, !0))
}, b.prototype._onMove = function (a) {
    this.isOpen && (a.preventDefault(), this._move(a))
}, b.prototype._onLeave = function () {
    this.isMouseOver = !1, this.isOpen && this.hide()
}, b.prototype._onLoad = function (a) {
    a.currentTarget.width && (this.isReady = !0, this.$notice.detach(), this.$flyout.html(this.$zoom), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading").addClass("is-ready"), a.data.call && a.data())
}, b.prototype._onError = function () {
    var a = this;
    this.$notice.text(this.opts.errorNotice), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading").addClass("is-error"), this.detachNotice = setTimeout(function () {
        a.$notice.detach(), a.detachNotice = null
    }, this.opts.errorDuration)
}, b.prototype._loadImage = function (b, c) {
    var d = new Image;
    this.$target.addClass("is-loading").append(this.$notice.text(this.opts.loadingNotice)), this.$zoom = a(d).on("error", a.proxy(this._onError, this)).on("load", c, a.proxy(this._onLoad, this)), d.style.position = "absolute", d.src = b
}, b.prototype._move = function (a) {
    if (0 === a.type.indexOf("touch")) {
        var b = a.touches || a.originalEvent.touches;
        g = b[0].pageX, h = b[0].pageY
    } else g = a.pageX || g, h = a.pageY || h;
    var i = this.$target.offset(),
        j = h - i.top,
        k = g - i.left,
        l = Math.ceil(j * f),
        m = Math.ceil(k * e);
    if (0 > m || 0 > l || m > c || l > d) this.hide();
    else {
        var n = -1 * l,
            o = -1 * m;
        this.$zoom.css({
            top: n,
            left: o
        }), this.opts.onMove.call(this, n, o)
    }
}, b.prototype.hide = function () {
    this.isOpen && this.opts.beforeHide.call(this) !== !1 && (this.$flyout.detach(), this.isOpen = !1, this.opts.onHide.call(this))
}, b.prototype.swap = function (b, c, d) {
    this.hide(), this.isReady = !1, this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), this.$notice.parent().length && this.$notice.detach(), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.$image.attr({
        src: b,
        srcset: a.isArray(d) ? d.join() : d
    }), this.$link.attr(this.opts.linkAttribute, c)
}, b.prototype.teardown = function () {
    this.hide(), this.$target.off(".easyzoom").removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), delete this.$link, delete this.$zoom, delete this.$image, delete this.$notice, delete this.$flyout, delete this.isOpen, delete this.isReady
}, a.fn.easyZoom = function (c) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var d = a.data(this, "easyZoom");
        d ? void 0 === d.isOpen && d._init() : a.data(this, "easyZoom", new b(this, c))
    })
}, "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(function () {
    return b
}) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = b)
}(jQuery);



    // Instantiate EasyZoom instances
    var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();

    // Setup thumbnails example
    var api1 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-thumbnails').data('easyZoom');

    $('.thumbnails').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        e.preventDefault();

        // Use EasyZoom's `swap` method
        api1.swap($this.data('standard'), $this.attr('href'));
    });

    // Setup toggles example
    var api2 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-toggle').data('easyZoom');

    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.data("active") === true) {
            $this.text("Switch on").data("active", false);
            api2.teardown();
        } else {
            $this.text("Switch off").data("active", true);
            api2._init();
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for easyzoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in `beforeShow` and `beforeHide` argument into `easyZoom` when you instantiate them.

```
var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom({
    beforeHide: function() {
        this.$flyout.fadeOut();
        return false;
    },
    beforeShow: function() {
        this.$flyout.show();
    }
});
```

```js
    /*!
     * @name        EasyZoom
     * @author      Matt Hinchliffe <>
     * @modified    Tuesday, September 6th, 2016
     * @version     2.4.0
     */
    ! function(a) {
      "use strict";

      function b(b, c) {
        this.$target = a(b), this.opts = a.extend({}, i, c, this.$target.data()), void 0 === this.isOpen && this._init()
      }
      var c, d, e, f, g, h, i = {
        loadingNotice: "Loading image",
        errorNotice: "The image could not be loaded",
        errorDuration: 2500,
        linkAttribute: "href",
        preventClicks: !0,
        beforeShow: a.noop,
        beforeHide: a.noop,
        onShow: a.noop,
        onHide: a.noop,
        onMove: a.noop
      };
      b.prototype._init = function() {
        this.$link = this.$target.find("a"), this.$image = this.$target.find("img"), this.$flyout = a('<div class="easyzoom-flyout" />'), this.$notice = a('<div class="easyzoom-notice" />'), this.$target.on({
          "mousemove.easyzoom touchmove.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onMove, this),
          "mouseleave.easyzoom touchend.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onLeave, this),
          "mouseenter.easyzoom touchstart.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onEnter, this)
        }), this.opts.preventClicks && this.$target.on("click.easyzoom", function(a) {
          a.preventDefault()
        })
      }, b.prototype.show = function(a, b) {
        var g, h, i, j, k = this;
        if (this.opts.beforeShow.call(this) !== !1) {
          if (!this.isReady) return this._loadImage(this.$link.attr(this.opts.linkAttribute), function() {
            (k.isMouseOver || !b) && k.show(a)
          });
          this.$target.append(this.$flyout), g = this.$target.width(), h = this.$target.height(), i = this.$flyout.width(), j = this.$flyout.height(), c = this.$zoom.width() - i, d = this.$zoom.height() - j, 0 > c && (c = 0), 0 > d && (d = 0), e = c / g, f = d / h, this.isOpen = !0, this.opts.onShow.call(this), a && this._move(a)
        }
      }, b.prototype._onEnter = function(a) {
        var b = a.originalEvent.touches;
        this.isMouseOver = !0, b && 1 != b.length || (a.preventDefault(), this.show(a, !0))
      }, b.prototype._onMove = function(a) {
        this.isOpen && (a.preventDefault(), this._move(a))
      }, b.prototype._onLeave = function() {
        this.isMouseOver = !1, this.isOpen && this.hide()
      }, b.prototype._onLoad = function(a) {
        a.currentTarget.width && (this.isReady = !0, this.$notice.detach(), this.$flyout.html(this.$zoom), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading").addClass("is-ready"), a.data.call && a.data())
      }, b.prototype._onError = function() {
        var a = this;
        this.$notice.text(this.opts.errorNotice), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading").addClass("is-error"), this.detachNotice = setTimeout(function() {
          a.$notice.detach(), a.detachNotice = null
        }, this.opts.errorDuration)
      }, b.prototype._loadImage = function(b, c) {
        var d = new Image;
        this.$target.addClass("is-loading").append(this.$notice.text(this.opts.loadingNotice)), this.$zoom = a(d).on("error", a.proxy(this._onError, this)).on("load", c, a.proxy(this._onLoad, this)), d.style.position = "absolute", d.src = b
      }, b.prototype._move = function(a) {
        if (0 === a.type.indexOf("touch")) {
          var b = a.touches || a.originalEvent.touches;
          g = b[0].pageX, h = b[0].pageY
        } else g = a.pageX || g, h = a.pageY || h;
        var i = this.$target.offset(),
          j = h - i.top,
          k = g - i.left,
          l = Math.ceil(j * f),
          m = Math.ceil(k * e);
        if (0 > m || 0 > l || m > c || l > d) this.hide();
        else {
          var n = -1 * l,
            o = -1 * m;
          this.$zoom.css({
            top: n,
            left: o
          }), this.opts.onMove.call(this, n, o)
        }
      }, b.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.isOpen && this.opts.beforeHide.call(this) !== !1 && (this.$flyout.detach(), this.isOpen = !1, this.opts.onHide.call(this))
      }, b.prototype.swap = function(b, c, d) {
        this.hide(), this.isReady = !1, this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), this.$notice.parent().length && this.$notice.detach(), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.$image.attr({
          src: b,
          srcset: a.isArray(d) ? d.join() : d
        }), this.$link.attr(this.opts.linkAttribute, c)
      }, b.prototype.teardown = function() {
        this.hide(), this.$target.off(".easyzoom").removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), delete this.$link, delete this.$zoom, delete this.$image, delete this.$notice, delete this.$flyout, delete this.isOpen, delete this.isReady
      }, a.fn.easyZoom = function(c) {
        return this.each(function() {
          var d = a.data(this, "easyZoom");
          d ? void 0 === d.isOpen && d._init() : a.data(this, "easyZoom", new b(this, c))
        })
      }, "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(function() {
        return b
      }) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = b)
    }(jQuery);



     // Instantiate EasyZoom instances
    var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom({
      beforeHide: function() {
        this.$flyout.fadeOut();
        return false;
      },
      beforeShow: function() {
        this.$flyout.show();
      }
    });

     // Setup thumbnails example
    var api1 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-thumbnails').data('easyZoom');

    $('.thumbnails').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      var $this = $(this);

      e.preventDefault();

      // Use EasyZoom's `swap` method
      api1.swap($this.data('standard'), $this.attr('href'));
    });

     // Setup toggles example
    var api2 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-toggle').data('easyZoom');

    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      if ($this.data("active") === true) {
        $this.text("Switch on").data("active", false);
        api2.teardown();
      } else {
        $this.text("Switch off").data("active", true);
        api2._init();
      }
    });
```

```css
.easyzoom {
  position: relative;
  /* 'Shrink-wrap' the element */
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.easyzoom img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.easyzoom.is-loading img {
  cursor: progress;
}
.easyzoom.is-ready img {
  cursor: default;
}
.easyzoom.is-error img {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.easyzoom-notice {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 150;
  width: 10em;
  margin: -1em 0 0 -5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
.easyzoom-flyout {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.easyzoom-flyout:hover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.easyzoom--overlay .easyzoom-flyout {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.easyzoom--adjacent .easyzoom-flyout {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
  <a href="http://radarmidcentury.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/z-danish-sideboard-hans-wegner-president-in-oak-1a.jpg">
    <img src="http://radarmidcentury.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/z-danish-sideboard-hans-wegner-president-in-oak-1a.jpg" alt="" width="608.917" height="405.833" />
  </a>
</div>
```

You can refer the flyout zoomed image using `this.$flyout` in the functions.

Return false if you want to stop the default `hide` or `show` function. Just remember to add the default behavior into your function if you are doing that.

In the example I did above, I do a fadeOut on the zoomed image and stop the flyout from detaching (default behavior is `detach()` the zoomed image element). Then, as the flyout element was faded out, I have to use `$.show()` or the element will be stuck at `display: none` and nothing will be shown on mouseover.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

'mouseleave' trigger _onLeave() which fire hide() which cause the zoomed div with image is removed from the DOM so any CSS transition or $().fadeOut() does not work. I removed hide() firing when mouseleave and change opacity in CSS and it seems to work now and anything else seems to be broken. Change opacity time as you wish.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh5jw5tb/4/)

```js
 /*!
 * @name        EasyZoom
 * @author      Matt Hinchliffe <>
 * @modified    Tuesday, September 6th, 2016
 * @version     2.4.0
 */
! function (a) {
 "use strict";

 function b(b, c) {
  this.$target = a(b), this.opts = a.extend({}, i, c, this.$target.data()), void 0 === this.isOpen && this._init()
 }
 var c, d, e, f, g, h, i = {
  loadingNotice: "Loading image",
  errorNotice: "The image could not be loaded",
  errorDuration: 2500,
  linkAttribute: "href",
  preventClicks: !0,
  beforeShow: a.noop,
  beforeHide: a.noop,
  onShow: a.noop,
  onHide: a.noop,
  onMove: a.noop
 };
 b.prototype._init = function () {
  this.$link = this.$target.find("a"), this.$image = this.$target.find("img"), this.$flyout = a('<div class="easyzoom-flyout" />'), this.$notice = a('<div class="easyzoom-notice" />'), this.$target.on({
   "mousemove.easyzoom touchmove.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onMove, this),
   "mouseleave.easyzoom touchend.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onLeave, this),
   "mouseenter.easyzoom touchstart.easyzoom": a.proxy(this._onEnter, this)
  }), this.opts.preventClicks && this.$target.on("click.easyzoom", function (a) {
   a.preventDefault()
  })
 }, b.prototype.show = function (a, b) {
  var g, h, i, j, k = this;
  if (this.opts.beforeShow.call(this) !== !1) {
   if (!this.isReady) return this._loadImage(this.$link.attr(this.opts.linkAttribute), function () {
    (k.isMouseOver || !b) && k.show(a)
   });
   this.$target.append(this.$flyout), g = this.$target.width(), h = this.$target.height(), i = this.$flyout.width(), j = this.$flyout.height(), c = this.$zoom.width() - i, d = this.$zoom.height() - j, 0 > c && (c = 0), 0 > d && (d = 0), e = c / g, f = d / h, this.isOpen = !0, this.opts.onShow.call(this), a && this._move(a)
  }
 }, b.prototype._onEnter = function (a) {
  var b = a.originalEvent.touches;
  this.isMouseOver = !0, b && 1 != b.length || (a.preventDefault(), this.show(a, !0))
 }, b.prototype._onMove = function (a) {
  this.isOpen && (a.preventDefault(), this._move(a))
 }, b.prototype._onLeave = function () {
  
  this.isMouseOver = !1, this.isOpen
 }, b.prototype._onLoad = function (a) {
  a.currentTarget.width && (this.isReady = !0, this.$notice.detach(), this.$flyout.html(this.$zoom), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading").addClass("is-ready"), a.data.call && a.data())
 }, b.prototype._onError = function () {
  var a = this;
  this.$notice.text(this.opts.errorNotice), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading").addClass("is-error"), this.detachNotice = setTimeout(function () {
   a.$notice.detach(), a.detachNotice = null
  }, this.opts.errorDuration)
 }, b.prototype._loadImage = function (b, c) {
  var d = new Image;
  this.$target.addClass("is-loading").append(this.$notice.text(this.opts.loadingNotice)), this.$zoom = a(d).on("error", a.proxy(this._onError, this)).on("load", c, a.proxy(this._onLoad, this)), d.style.position = "absolute", d.src = b
 }, b.prototype._move = function (a) {
  if (0 === a.type.indexOf("touch")) {
   var b = a.touches || a.originalEvent.touches;
   g = b[0].pageX, h = b[0].pageY
  } else g = a.pageX || g, h = a.pageY || h;
  var i = this.$target.offset(),
   j = h - i.top,
   k = g - i.left,
   l = Math.ceil(j * f),
   m = Math.ceil(k * e);
  if (0 > m || 0 > l || m > c || l > d) this.hide();
  else {
   var n = -1 * l,
    o = -1 * m;
   this.$zoom.css({
    top: n,
    left: o
   }), this.opts.onMove.call(this, n, o)
  }
 }, b.prototype.hide = function () {
    
  this.isOpen && this.opts.beforeHide.call(this) !== !1 && (this.$flyout.detach(), this.isOpen = !1, this.opts.onHide.call(this))
 }, b.prototype.swap = function (b, c, d) {
  this.hide(), this.isReady = !1, this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), this.$notice.parent().length && this.$notice.detach(), this.$target.removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.$image.attr({
   src: b,
   srcset: a.isArray(d) ? d.join() : d
  }), this.$link.attr(this.opts.linkAttribute, c)
 }, b.prototype.teardown = function () {
  this.hide(), this.$target.off(".easyzoom").removeClass("is-loading is-ready is-error"), this.detachNotice && clearTimeout(this.detachNotice), delete this.$link, delete this.$zoom, delete this.$image, delete this.$notice, delete this.$flyout, delete this.isOpen, delete this.isReady
 }, a.fn.easyZoom = function (c) {
  return this.each(function () {
   var d = a.data(this, "easyZoom");
   d ? void 0 === d.isOpen && d._init() : a.data(this, "easyZoom", new b(this, c))
  })
 }, "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(function () {
  return b
 }) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = b)
}(jQuery);



  // Instantiate EasyZoom instances
  var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();

  // Setup thumbnails example
  var api1 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-thumbnails').data('easyZoom');

  $('.thumbnails').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   var $this = $(this);

   e.preventDefault();

   // Use EasyZoom's `swap` method
   api1.swap($this.data('standard'), $this.attr('href'));
  });

  // Setup toggles example
  var api2 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-toggle').data('easyZoom');

  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
   var $this = $(this);

   if ($this.data("active") === true) {
    $this.text("Switch on").data("active", false);
    api2.teardown();
   } else {
    $this.text("Switch off").data("active", true);
    api2._init();
   }
  });
```

```css
.easyzoom {
 position: relative;
 /* 'Shrink-wrap' the element */
 display: inline-block;
 *display: inline;
 *zoom: 1;
}
.easyzoom img {vertical-align: bottom;}
.easyzoom.is-loading img {cursor: progress;}
.easyzoom.is-ready img {cursor: default;}
.easyzoom.is-error  img {cursor: not-allowed;}
.easyzoom-notice {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 z-index: 150;
 width: 10em;
 margin: -1em 0 0 -5em;
 line-height: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 background: #FFF;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}

.easyzoom-flyout {
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #FFF;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.easyzoom-flyout:hover {
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #FFF;
  opacity:1;

}
.easyzoom--overlay .easyzoom-flyout {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.easyzoom--adjacent .easyzoom-flyout {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
    <a href="http://radarmidcentury.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/z-danish-sideboard-hans-wegner-president-in-oak-1a.jpg">
     <img src="http://radarmidcentury.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/z-danish-sideboard-hans-wegner-president-in-oak-1a.jpg" alt="" width="608.917" height="405.833" />
    </a>
   </div>
```